# jQuery datepicker in HTML form to update MySQL rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I've done heaps of research on this topic but for some reason nothings working!

I want to use the datepicker widget to update a row in MySQL (which has a date column). For some reason, whenever I try to update the row (which works for other input things) it says in my MySQL table 0000-00-00 ??

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
  </script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<p> Date: <input name="slot_date" id="datepicker" > &nbsp; <input type="text" id="alternate" size="30"></p>
```

My PHP:

```
  if( isset($_POST['btn-book']) ) { 

 $slot_date = date('yy-mm-dd',strtotime($_POST['slot_date']));
 $slot_line=$_POST['slot_line'];
 $reason=$_POST['reason'];
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $sql="UPDATE appointments SET slot_date='$slot_date', slot_line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);


 if($result){
  header ("Location: homepage_loggedin_book_success.php");
 }else {
  echo "ERROR";
 } 
}
```

Anyway, i've been trying for ages but the datepicker wont enter into my MySql table??

Comment: Some datepicker plugin uses different form hidden name, try to print_r($_POST) see if any alternative date field in hidden; Alternatively, echo $sql, see what actually pass-in for $slot_date

Comment: post more of your php for $slot_date and stuff.

Comment: It looks like the actual date is hidden as #alternate. What your #datepicker field date format looks like when you pick a date: yy-mm-dd or DD, d MM, yy? both of these 2 formats will be converted to 0000-00-00 at mysql. A valid default data format for mysql will be YYYY-mm-dd otherwise you need convert

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://php.net/date) to enforce your desired format.

```
$slot_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($slot_date)); # will output 2016-08-16
$sql="UPDATE appointments SET slot_date='$slot_date', slot_line='$slot_line', reason='$reason' WHERE id='$id'";
```

### Your code may be prone to SQL injections. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.

Answer (score 0):

In the original form which created the record, is everything being set correctly? Are the `slot_line` and `reason` fields updating correctly? If they aren't the problem could be in your PHP. Could you post more of the PHP code for context?

Comment: everything updates correctly except for 'slot_date'. I posted more of my PHP code, but everything in there works apart from the stuff for the date